# How to return the function in a closure in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future

eg:

```dart
Future<int> _test1() async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) {
    return 1;
  });
}

void _onTapButton() async {
  await _test1().then((value) {
    print('a');
    if (value == 1) {
      print('return');
      return;
    }
  });

  print('b');
}
```

When I call `_onTapButton`, console print **`a`** **`return`** **`b`** not **`a`** **`return`**.

That is to say the `return` in `_test1().then` didn't return the function `_onTapButton`.

Is there any way I can return function `_onTapButton` in `_test1().then`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `then` part is a callback that will be executed upon completion of your future, and `return` is meant in the scope of this callback, not your `_onTapButton` function.

If you want to wait for the future, and if it results 1, print `return` and return from `_onTapButton`, you can try this:

```
void _onTapButton() async {
   final value = await _test1();
   print('a');
   if (value == 1) {
      print('return');
      return;
   }
   print('b');
}
```